# Changing the color of \ref within the same document

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, color

Is there a way to reference things with \ref using a different color than with what `\hypersetup` assigns it? That is, I would like to reference a theorem with blue text in general, but at some point I'd like to reference it with red text.  I've tried using `\textcolor` but that doesn't seem to override it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can switch colours mid-document using `\hypersetup`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks % Defaults to red
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}\label{sec:section}

See Section~\ref{sec:section}.

\hypersetup{linkcolor=green}

See Section~\ref{sec:section}.

\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}

See Section~\ref{sec:section}.

\end{document}
```